# realm configuration has protected access in io.realm.realmConfiguration

Tags: android, realm

this is on error when i want create new clsss from ReamlConfiguration

this is my code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration=new RealmConfiguration().Builder
            .build;
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

}
}
```

Comment: `new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();`

Comment: You need to move those parentheses. Yes, really.